# Add the XAttribute to XElement if attribute exists in the element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

Need to add

```
XAttribute newatt = new XAttribute("TAG", value);
```

to `XElement elem`, but the `elem` could already contain the attribute with the name `"TAG"`, so the `elem.Add(newatt);` would give error. The workaround I use at the moment is to check first:

```
if (elem.Attribute("TAG") != null) // check if attribute exists                        
    elem.SetAttributeValue("TAG", newatt.Value.ToString()); // Attribute exists
else
    elem.Add(newatt); // Attribute does not exist
```

Is there a shorter way to do this task, perhaps already available `XElement` function that checks for the existing `"TAG"` maybe (I am aware that it is possible to wrap the above snippet into a function)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to check whether the attribute already exists before using `SetAttributeValue`. Just:

```
// Unconditional
elem.SetAttributeValue("TAG", value);
```

(There's no point even creating the `XAttribute` yourself.)

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The value is assigned to the attribute with the specified name. If no attribute with the specified name exists, a new attribute is added. If the value is null, the attribute with the specified name, if any, is deleted.